# Android Studio Build Tools confusion

Tags: android-studio

I am unable to build a project due to Android Studio or possibly me getting confused with the version of Build Tools in use.
The error (below) shows 21.0.0 is required but 19.1 is being used.

**Messages Window**

```
Error:Execution failed 
fortask ':customGridViewmaster:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Multi dex requires Build Tools 21.0.0 / Current: 19.1
```

This code extract taken from build.gradle would suggest that it is actually set to 24.0.1, am I looking in the right place?

**gradle.build**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
```